# Is five hours between flights in Munich enough to visit the city?

Tags: transit, munich

I have five hours and fifteen minutes between flight landing to next flight in Munich.  Is this enough time to have a quick trip into the city?

If I check my bag in all the way to Barcelona from the US do I have to retrieve it in Munich to go into the city.

Comment: Many informations are missing, are you a US citizen? do you need a visa for the Schenguen area? What is your flight itinerary? How did you book it? The trains that go to the city are running every 10 minutes or so and you can reach the center of the city in 40 minutes. Which would give you roughly 1 hour to visit the city and come back with no stress.

Comment: I am US citizen and traveled to Germany and Spain and did not need a visa for either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your inbound flight lands on time, let's make a rough calculation :

- 20 minutes to exit the plane / airport (could be more during peak hours)
- 30 minutes to get to Munich downtown (again could be more during peak hours)
- 30 minutes to get back to the airport
- 1h00 at the airport for the security checks

So this leaves you approximately 3h00 in Munich. But you need to take into consideration few points :

- I took an optimal timing (ie landing on time, no commuting issue and minimum time at the airport).
- If you plan to exit the airport, I would suggest you to take on your luggage with you because if for any reason you aren't able to take the second flight, then the company will have to take your luggage out of the plane (which is a pain for them) and then you'll also miss your luggage if you have to stay overnight in Munich.

So you aren't forced to take your luggage with you but I would recommend you to do so...

Comment: If you take the S-Bahn to Marienplatz, it will take actually 40 (S8) - 50 minutes (S1)